# Group by method (in pandas) not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to work with [Stack Exchange data](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (specifically, [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) questions).

I am trying to find which were the **top three tags for questions** for all the years; and then construct a stacked barplot for the same.

The example dataset that I am using below is not the actual one, however, resembles the original *stack exchange* data.

The initial data frame looks like this:-

[image: Original dataframe]

After some wrangling (code below):-

```
import re

def my_function(x):
    
    output = []
    
    for s in re.findall("(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)", x):
        output.append(s)
        
    output2 = ", ".join(output)
    
    return output2


df3['Tags'] = [my_function(x) for x in df3['Tags']]

df3_new = df3.assign(Tags=df3['Tags'].str.split(',')).explode('Tags')
```

The new data frame looks something like this:-

[image: New data frame]

Notice how the index is repeated? So, I decide to reset index.

`df3_new.reset_index(drop=True)`

and now the data frame looks like this:-

[image]

Finally, I use **group by** because I wish to obtain how many times a tag was repeated in any given year. I can then (later on) filter for the top three.

```
df3_groupby = df3_new.groupby(['Tags']).size().reset_index(name='Count')

df3_groupby
```

[image]

Notice above how *response* and *thankful* are repeated? Let's try one more group by.

```
df3_groupby2 = df3_new.groupby(['Year', 'Tags'])['Year'].size().reset_index(name='Count')

df3_groupby2
```

[image]

What about **value_counts**?

[image]

I have tried some other things as well like, dropping the *Body* column, making a *set* for tags, however, nothing seems to be working.

I would really appreciate help in either solving the above problem...or if there's a better way of knowing which question tags have the highest frequency in any given year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with space - need `,` with or without space in `join` and `str.split`:

```
import re

def my_function(x):
    
    output = []
    
    for s in re.findall("(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)", x):
        output.append(s)
        
    #removed space 
    output2 = ",".join(output)
    
    return output2


df3['Tags'] = [my_function(x) for x in df3['Tags']]

#here is , without space
df3_new = df3.assign(Tags=df3['Tags'].str.split(',')).explode('Tags')
```

---

```
import re

def my_function(x):
    
    output = []
    
    for s in re.findall("(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)", x):
        output.append(s)
        
    #here is space after , 
    output2 = ", ".join(output)
    
    return output2


df3['Tags'] = [my_function(x) for x in df3['Tags']]

#added space to split
df3_new = df3.assign(Tags=df3['Tags'].str.split(', ')).explode('Tags')
```

But simplier is use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for splitted lists, then join and split is not necessary:

```
df3_new = df3.assign(Tags=df3['Tags'].str.findall(r"(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)")).explode('Tags')
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I just tried what you suggested and you are a genius! I could not have thought of a missing space in a million years. It works on my example dataset...I will also try on the real dataset. Thanks a ton, one more time!